# How to implement a MetadataProvider that reads from database

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm adding SSO support to a spring-based application using the spring-security-saml extension. The idea will be that an IDP can register to use SSO with my application by filling out a form in the UI, specifying their *entityId*, *SSO authentication URL* (for SP-initialized login), and *public X.509 certificate*. This seems to be a common workflow for SaaS applications with SSO support.

I haven't yet been able to find a clean way of implementing this with the spring saml extension, and am wondering if there is one. `FilesystemMetadataProvider` and `HTTPMetadataProvider` provide support for loading IDP metadata from an XML file or an HTTP GET, respectively, but I need to instead generate the IDP metadata from the above attributes that are stored in the database.

My current thinking is to use `ResourceBackedMetadataProvider` and use an implementation of `Resource` that fetches the metadata attributes from the database for each registered IDP. It would look something like:

```
class DatabaseBackedResource implements Resource {

    MetadataDao metadataDao; // autowired

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws ResourceException {
        Collection<MetadataPojo> idpMetadata = metadataDao.getMetadata();
        return convertMetadataPojosToInputStream(idpMetadata);
    }

    private InputStream convertMetadataPojosToInputStream(Collection<MetadataPojo> metadata) {
        // somehow convert attributes to XMLObject
        // then write XMLObject to input stream
        // ...
    }

    // implementations of other methods
    // ...

}
```

where `MetadataPojo` is simply a wrapper object of the above 3 attributes provided by an IDP. What I'm not sure about is how to generate a valid IDP metadata java object, given some attributes, using the spring saml extension. I see that `AbstractMetadataProvider#unmarshallMetadata(InputStream)` converts the metadata input stream into an `XMLObject`, but it is not clear to me how I will convert my collection of `MetadataPojo`s into an `XMLObject`.

In short, is there a tool in the spring saml extension library to build an IDP metadata xml object given a list of string attributes? Or, taking a step back, is there a better way to implement a `MetadataProvider` that fetches the metadata information from a database instead of a file or url?

*Update:*

I implemented the above `MetadataProvider` implementation and `Resource` subclass and it's been working like a charm.  To generate the IDP metadata documents I used various subclasses of `AbstractSAMLObjectBuilder` (i.e. `EntityDescriptorBuilder`, `IDPSSODescriptorBuilder`, `KeyDescriptorBuilder`, etc.) and that worked pretty cleanly. It would be nice if the Spring SAML library had an `IDPMetadataGenerator` class like the `MetadataGenerator` that exists for SP metadata.

If there was a cleaner way about this, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You right - I Didn't want to handle the creation of the metadata. So I just asked for the user for its metadata. Could you please provide your work? Thanks.